# spaCy: Matcher end token offset not what I am expecting

Tags: python, nlp, matcher, spacy

With spaCy (`2.0.11` according to `spacy.info()`), I'm trying to identify token patterns using the Matcher, but am not getting the expected results. The token offsets in the match objects do not correspond to the offsets of the tokens that *should* be matched in the text.

Here is a simplified code snippet to show what I'm doing:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load('en')

text = "This has not gone far. The end."
doc = nlp(text)

pattern1 = [{'POS': 'VERB'}, {'LEMMA': 'not'}, {'POS': 'VERB'}] # match has not gone
pattern2 = [{'POS': 'DET'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}] # match The end

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

matcher.add('rule1', None, pattern1)
matcher.add('rule2', None, pattern2)

matches = matcher(doc)

for match in matches:
    print(doc[match[1]], doc[match[2]], match)
```

The output I get is:

```
has far (15137773209560627690, 1, 4)
The . (16952143625379849586, 6, 8)
```

The output I'm expecting is:

```
has gone (15137773209560627690, 1, 3)
The end (16952143625379849586, 6, 7)
```

So the end token offset of the match is that of the token *after* the last token matched by the pattern. Is this the expected behaviour?

More generally, I'm trying to produce the TokensRegex-style behaviour of being able to add custom annotations to individual tokens within a given match (e.g. adding a negated=TRUE annotation to "has" and "gone" and a negation=TRUE annotation to the adverb "not" within the same match). Adding a single annotation to a match with a callback function is possible, but that's not quite what I'm after. Is this possible (yet)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're only looking at the start and end *token*, instead of the matched span. The `end` index of a span is always exclusive, so `doc[2:4]` will be token 2 *up to* token 4. I just tried your example and printed each matched span's text, and I'm seeing the following output:

```
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span.text)

# has not gone
# The end
```

To answer your second question: You could use the [custom extension attributes](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#section-custom-components-extensions) like `token._.negated` and `token._.negation` to achieve something very similar. If your negation rule matches, you could create a `Span` for the match, iterate over the tokens and set the respective attributes. To make this more elegant, you can also wrap that logic in a [pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#section-custom-components), so it's run automatically when you call `nlp` on a text.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy and helpful response! Regarding the second point, is it possible to write a generic component to deal with all rules and their specific set of custom extension attributes? I can't see how to do this without creating a new component per pattern/rule, which is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I hope I understand your question correctly but yes, that should be no problem. The `match_id` of a match is the hash of the rule name. This means that `doc.vocab.strings[match_id]` will be `'rule1'` etc. So you could create one matcher with multiple rules and patterns, and based on the match ID, the component would then decide how to set the attributes. You probably also want to implement it as a class that sets up the matcher and patterns once and has a `__call__` method that's applied to the `Doc`. [Here are some examples](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#component-example2).